# Transform categorical column into dummy columns using Power Query M

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Using Power Query "M" language, how would you transform a categorical column containing discrete values into multiple "dummy" columns? I come from the Python world and there are several ways to do this but one way would be below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dataset = pd.DataFrame(list('ABCDACDEAABADDA'),
               columns=['my_col'])
>>> dataset
   my_col
0       A
1       B
2       C
3       D
4       A
5       C
6       D
7       E
8       A
9       A
10      B
11      A
12      D
13      D
14      A
>>> pd.get_dummies(dataset)
    my_col_A  my_col_B  my_col_C  my_col_D  my_col_E
0          1         0         0         0         0
1          0         1         0         0         0
2          0         0         1         0         0
3          0         0         0         1         0
4          1         0         0         0         0
5          0         0         1         0         0
6          0         0         0         1         0
7          0         0         0         0         1
8          1         0         0         0         0
9          1         0         0         0         0
10         0         1         0         0         0
11         1         0         0         0         0
12         0         0         0         1         0
13         0         0         0         1         0
14         1         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Is there a fixed and/or fairly small number of columns in your desired dummy table?

Comment: The shape of the dummy table outputted is the shape of [n_rows, n unique values in that column]. In my example, A, B, C, D, E are the unique values in that column so 5 columns are created  - one for each unique value.

Comment: I understand that. The simplest approach would be to just define each column separately, but that won't work if your number of distinct values is variable. If you know how many you have a priori, you can get away with it though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a scaleable approach, not a custom hand-coded conditional approach like "if A then 1, If B then 1..." because I plan to apply this on future categorical columns of varying unique values.

Comment: That's what I figured. Just checking though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. Here's an easy, scalable method I've found:

---

1. Create a custom column of all ones (Add Column > Custom Column > Formula = 1).
2. Add an index column (Add Column > Index Column).
3. Pivot on the custom column (select `my_col` > Transform > Pivot Column).
4. Replace null values with 0 (select all columns > Transform > Replace Values).

---

Here's what the M code looks like for this process:

```
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Custom", each 1),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Index", List.Distinct(#"Added Index"[my_col]), "my_col", "Custom"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"))
```

---

Once you've completed the above, you can remove the index column if desired.