# Convert a single column with a list of values into one hot encoding using Power Query

Tags: python, excel, powerquery

For now I have following table in Excel, which makes it inconvenient to use for some further processing.

| ID | Segments |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Food |
| 2 | Automation |
| 3 | Mechatronics |
| 4 | Automation;Mechatronics |

What I would like to achieve, is one hot encoding of this data, which should look as follows. I'm trying to use Power Query for that.

| ID | Food | Automation | Mechatronics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I have found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49198365/1907924) but with a simpler example, where we always have just a single value in a column. I have tried suggested approach but modified it a bit, by splitting my column by `;` into multiple ones and then trying to pivot for every one of a splatted columns. Unfortunately it's resulting in an error as we are trying to create duplicated columns that way.

There is at least 30 distinct segments I may have. It seems that there are at most 5 of those combined for single record. Adding this note so that it's easier to find a balance between automation and manual work.

In worst case when there is no simple solution using Power Query, I can do this operation using Python (don't know how to do it in this complex case too thought) and reimport it later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Power Query, Split Column by Delimiter, there is an Advanced option to Split into Rows.

[image]

Add a custom column of just the number 1, then pivot

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think that splitting into rows instead of columns would do the trick.